# I am getting a strange cluster name in Cluster Events error message

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I need some help please.

I have a 2-node Windows cluster configured with WSFC (cluster name = **ABCCluster**).
Node 1 named **Node1**
Node 2 named **Node2**

SQL 2019 instance installed and named **INSTANCE**
Availability Group configured and named **INSTANCE_AG**
Availability Group listener prestaged and named **AGL_INSTANCE**

In Failover Cluster Manager, Cluster Events, I get following error:

*Cluster network name resource failed registration of one or more associated DNS names(s) because the access to update the secure DNS Zone was denied.*
*Cluster Network name: '**INSTANCE_AG_AGL_INSTANCE**'
DNS Zone: 'our.domain.com'
Ensure that cluster name object (CNO) is granted permission to the Secure DNS Zone*

**Question 1:**
Where has that strange Cluster name come from i.e. '**INSTANCE_AG_AGL_INSTANCE**'? The cluster name in Failover Cluster Manager is **ABCCluster**

**Question 2:**
The **prestaged** listener name has been attached to that strange cluster name, has prestaging the listener got anything to do with this error message?

Question 3:
As it is now, automatic failover for the AG happened from Node1 replica to Node2 replica when I stopped the SQL service on Node1 (which was previously the primary replica in the AG). However, when I stop the service on Node2, it doesn't failover automatically back to Node1. Node1 rather stays in 'RESOLVING' state for some time until the SQL service is started back on Node2 and then the Node1 replica resolves as 'secondary'. So, I have only a one-directional automatic failover.

I would appreciate any ideas on what I'm doing wrong please.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1: Where has that strange Cluster name come from i.e. 'INSTANCE_AG_AGL_INSTANCE'? The cluster name in Failover Cluster Manager is ABCCluster

This is the name of the network name resource created for the listener, this shows you used the wizard to create the listener as the wizard uses the naming convention of #AGName#_#DNSName#. You can create your own and name it how you like without using the wizard. Up to you, this has no bearing on anything, really.

Example: The network name resource has the value of AG3_AG3Listener but that's not the DNS name or the computer object name in AD (as the DNS name and CO name must be the same). You'll notice (I created it with the wizard to show the point) that the naming convention is AGName_ListenerName as the "Name" of the resource in the cluster.
[image: cluster resource name]

> Question 2: The prestaged listener name has been attached to that strange cluster name, has prestaging the listener got anything to do with this error message?

The listener dns name is a property of the cluster resource. The cluster resource has its own name, which is this name. These two are not the same thing.

Example: From the above example, here is what the actual DNS and computer object names in AD are.

[image: dns name]

> Question 3: As it is now, automatic failover for the AG happened from Node1 replica to Node2 replica when I stopped the SQL service on Node1 (which was previously the primary replica in the AG). However, when I stop the service on Node2, it doesn't failover automatically back to Node1. Node1 rather stays in 'RESOLVING' state for some time until the SQL service is started back on Node2 and then the Node1 replica resolves as 'secondary'. So, I have only a one-directional automatic failover.

Look at your cluster logs, they will tell you why. Since it's a 2 node cluster, chances are you're just hitting the 1 (N-1 failovers by default) failover that you have and thus the cluster says, nope, you hit your configured limit so I'm not failing that over again. This can be changed and is user configurable for number of failures and time period.

Powershell, showing the defaults are set:
[image: powershell failover defaults]

FCM (GUI) of the same information:
[image: gui failover defaults]

Comment: thank you so much for your time and patience to guide me through this. You have provided a lot of very helpful information for me to carefully work my way through. Thanks again.

Comment: In your Powershell commands above, please what is FL*

Comment: e.g. you have :  Get-ClusterGroup  -Name AG3 | FL*

Comment: thanks again for your help. Just one more question please. Given that it would seem that the listener that the wizard has unknowingly created is not required, since I have the prestaged one in DNS, which is the one configured in SSMS, can I delete the wizard one from AD?

Comment: just to say again, I'm not sure if you noticed my previous question about what FL* is in your Powershell command above. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: FL is shorthand for `format-list` in powershell. There are multiple parts to a listener, the AD object, the DNS entries, the cluster resource. All of those need to exist (except in certain scenarios such as workgroup clustering or read-scale). Don't delete anything.

Comment: thank you so much for all your help and time

Comment: another quick question relating to the listener created by the automation (not the wizard) i.e. the one named 'AGName_PrestagedListenerName'. This listener has now been prestaged by including it in DNS. It is in there with the same IP as the original prestaged listener. So we now have two listener names with same IP address in DNS. I can ping both, and connect to them in SSMS. However in FCM, the AG role resource shows only the original listener, so that is the one it is using. I however don't see AD objects for either of them. So how can I suppress the listener error message?

Comment: Please create a new question with data, I'm not sure what exactly is being attmpted as you'd intentionally be creating a duplicate IP on the network which is a problem.

Comment: thanks for your response, points noted. I read your previous answers again and see that the Listener DNS name and the network resource name #AGName#_#DNSName# are two different things. It seems the computer object name for the listener (with the listener DNS name) is missing in AD and the Cluster name does not have the permissions to it in AD. I think that's the issue that needs resolving. Thanks again for your time

Comment: please is the network name resource  **AG3_AG3Listener** (in your example above) the same as the Listener virtual network name (VNN)? Does this need  to have an entry in DNS as well as an AD CNO? Bear in mind the Listener DNS name is already in DNS as **AG3Listener**. Thank you

Comment: No, Ag3_AG3Listener is the cluster resource name, AG3Listener is the DNS name and AG3Listener is the name of the computer object in this AD integrated environment.

Comment: thank you for clarifying. So is the **Listener Virtual Network Name (VNN)** AG3Listener  i.e.  the listener name in DNS and the computer object?

Comment: In this case, yes.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Apologies for delay in responding, just logging in now. Much appreciated

Comment: apologies to trouble you with this again. Could you kindly advise me please? Do you foresee any issue with setting the Failover Period to zero? The reason I ask is because I had a look in the legacy system and found that the settings for failover threshold and failover period were left as defaults of 1 and 6 respectively. If I need to change my current settings back to defaults, would it be ok for me to change it in the FCM back to the default settings of 1 and 6 respectively?